# Since double and float represent the same data type (usually), which is preferable?

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, avr, data-type, avr-gcc

It looks like on ATMega based boards, `float` and `double` are equivalent 32-bit (4-byte) data types.

However, on the Arduino Due, `doubles` are 64-bit (8-byte) where `floats` are 32-bit (4-byte), same as the ATMega boards.

I also saw one source on avr-gcc that listed `double` as non-standard.

So, when writing code for ATMega based boards are `floats` preferable to using `doubles`, since that would make the code equivalent for Due boards? Or are `doubles` preferable for any reason?

Comment: I would use `float` so that anyone reading my code, who may not know about the non-standard AVR `double`, knows what precision to expect. But this is more personal preference than a hard rule (hence I do not consider it a “real” answer).

Comment: I think that's fairly solid reasoning; one might not expect the 'double' to really be a float if they're coming from another platform.

Answer (score 2):

See [avr-gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc)

> Deviations from the Standard
>
> **double**
>
> double is only 32 bits wide and implemented in the same way as float

---

> when writing code for ATMega based boards ...

They are the same, therefore.

---

*(Edited to add)*

> When writing code, is it then preferable to using one over the other?

I don't really understand your question. You asked about writing code for the ATMega based boards. Do you really mean, if you are writing code for the Due? The quick answer would be, on the Due, double takes twice the RAM, however it is over twice as precise - around 7.2 decimal digits for float compared to 15.9 for double. (I'm not sure about the speed, probably double would be slower, unless it is implemented in floating-point hardware - however I cannot see any reference to that on the AT91SAM3X8E datasheet).

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

If you want more precision (however slower and taking more RAM) then you could use `double` - which won't make any difference on the ATmega based boards, but will on the Due.

---

As Edgar Bonet said:

> I would use float so that anyone reading my code, who may not know about the non-standard AVR double, knows what precision to expect.

That makes quite a bit of sense.

---

I warn you though that "preferable" is subjective. It is close to asking "what is best"? To which the reply is: "best for what?"

Comment: On ATMega boards, yes, they are the same. If you then take the code to an Arduino Due, they are no longer the same if using `double`, but the same if using `float`. When writing code, is it then preferable to using one over the other? Why or why not?

Comment: See amended reply.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking I'm only targeting ATMega architectures right now, I _thought_ I was writing code that was consistent across all arduinos. I did not ask which was _best_, though I think I'm answering my own question in that `float` is more well known, a better cross-architecture description of the datatype, and consistent across more arduinos.

Comment: Would it make more sense if I added "When writing Arduino code _for an unknown board_, is it then preferable to use one over the other?"

Comment: I suppose. \*shrug\* - when dealing with boards which may have limited RAM and Flash, it isn't always possible to code generically.

Comment: At the outset of Arduino programming, I thought they were at least attempting to make the code as hardware-agnostic as they could. In this spirit, I think I'll use `floats` from here on.

Comment: This answer is no more up to date with avr-gcc, which suports 64-bit double (and long dounble) since v10.  See for example the avr-gcc wiki page you linked.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Well, yes, but using a configuration option, not the default. `In avr-gcc v10 and higher, the layout of double and long double are determined by configure options --with-double= and --with-long-double=, respectively.` Bear in mind that using more precise floating point will take longer, so your application would need to choose precision over speed.

Comment: And take more memory, which you may not want to take on a processor with limited RAM.

Comment: @Nick Gammon: Of course it's about precision, which was not the point of my comment.  Besides that, avr-gcc v10+ supports `-mdouble=64`.  The only reason to default it to 32 bits was to align with older (not standard-compliant) versions of avr-gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are preferable.

Unless your microcontroller has a hardware floating point unit using float or double results in huge overheads for your program.

So instead use integer mathematics whenever possible.

Instead of working in Volts, work in millivolts, for example.

However, if your MCU does have an FPU, and some modern more powerful ones do, then you should use the size of float or double that is native to the FPU. If it is a 32 bit FPU then use float. If it is a 64 bit FPU then you can use double.

Comment: do you have any actual benchmarks of the "huge overheads"? less efficient sure, but I've never really had it be a problem to use floating point on arduino.

Comment: `int a; void setup() { a = 1; } void loop() { a = a * 2; }` uses 482 bytes. Change the `int` to a `float` it slmost doubles to 878 bytes. Even worse if you change the `2` to `2.0`, while it's `int` - you end up with 1086 bytes. Massive increases. And that's not even mentioning how long it takes to run. I'll do a crude benchmark.

Comment: Multiplying 1 by 2 until it exceeds 32768 (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc) with `int` takes 12 microseconds. Using `float` it takes 148 microseconds. That's more than ten times longer for just that one simple operation.

Comment: Interestingly, multiplying an integer by `2.0` takes even longer - 208 microseconds. 17 times longer.

Comment: Fixed point takes more ops than just integer multiply, and we should be comparing 32-bit values on both sides. in a test of float `(a*b)` and long `(a*b/1000)`, as would be the case if you did operations in mV, floating point is faster. That's not calculating the extra high byte that's necessary for real fixed point, then again fixed point would benefit from an easier divisor. Addition will certainly remain faster in fixed point. I don't think float vs fixed is as clear cut as the arduino SE community makes it out to be.

Comment: @BrettAM: When doing fixed point, you would never scale by 1000, always by a power of two. And no, you should not compare at 32 bits: you should compare 32-bit floats vs. fixed point of the smallest size that is precise enough for the job, which will often be 16 bits, and sometimes even 8. I've done a 16-bit fixed-point implementation of `cos()` and `sin()` that is 15.7 times faster than the standard `<math.h>` functions.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I mentioned that the divisor is bad, its taken from the answer that suggested it. A 6.10 fixed point multiplication results in a 12.20 (32 bit) result; so unless their numbers fit in 8 the multiplication would need to take place in 32 bits. The overhead of writing a custom fixed point `cos()` (or even downloading one) is much greater than having a few slow trig functions for most applications here on arduino SE.

Comment: @BrettAM: The answer did not suggest a division, it suggested using millivolts, which is not the same. Typically you would either `analogRead(pin) * 39U >> 3` or `analogRead(pin) * 1250UL >> 8`, depending on the required precision. And you do not need to multiply in 32 bits: you can do a 16×16→16 multiply in assembly, or use the `_Fract` or `_Accum` data types. But then I agree that many projects have enough CPU cycles to spare to make fixed point irrelevant.